# open url in external browser instead of in-app mobile browser using php for ios

Tags: php, android, ios, mobile, user-agent

I am using below code which is working perfectly for android mobile but its not working on ios.
What will be the perfect way to achieve this on ios?

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (strpos($userAgent, 'Instagram')) {
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= test');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    @readfile($file);
}
else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

I want to open index.php on external browser of mobile app

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs server-side, not on the iOS device.

Instead, could you just use the homepage URL, which defaults to running the index.php file's code?

`header('Location: siteaddress.com');`

Comment: My code is working properly on Android mobile but not on ios devices. The main problem is I don't want to use in-app browser of Instagram. I want to use chrome browser whenever my links get clicked